# ubuntu 14.04.2 on 5th gen intel chips

Tags: intel

Does ubuntu 14.04.2 work well with the 5th gen Intel processors? And also, does it support GT 820M graphic cards? In short, I have a HP 15-r240tx laptop and will I be able to install ubuntu in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work fine. You can find a list of supported hardware from most vendors at http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/desktop/

Do not rule out Ubuntu not working just based on that list though -- if that was the case, I wouldn't be typing this message now (mine is not on the list).

You can always make a live USB stick or live DVD to try out Ubuntu on your hardware as well. To make a live DVD, just burn the .iso file you downloaded to a DVD ( If you have Windows 7 and below, you will need 3rd party software to do this correctly). If you want to make a live USB stick, just follow the directions here:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick

Comment: Generally: I'd recommend paying good attention to the content of the `Device manager` (right click `My computer` then select `Manage`). Take notes on what hardware you have and look it up one the net w.r.t. Linux drivers and known issues.

Comment: @steaksauce: Don't you think if a particular hardware is not listed on the supported hardware list then running the OS might damage the hardware?

Comment: And the very basic reason that I have asked the very first question was because It wasn't specified that ubuntu 14.04 was tested on the 5th gen chip sets and 820M graphic cards when I checked on the ubuntu website.

Comment: @Dragon it would not harm your hardware. The worse that could happen is Ubuntu not working (as long as you try it out with a live DVD or USB before installing). Part of the live media's purpose is to test it out on a machine before installing it.

Comment: No problem! Whether it works or not, I would like to know :)

Comment: It did! :) but now i have another problem, I have two unallocated spaces on my hardrive and between those are c drive with my windows file and system reserve space! Is there any way that I could merge these two unallocated spaces?

Comment: @Dragon that question is getting off-topic for this post. I would suggest looking around here for someone that has asked that question (I'm sure you're not the first to ask). If you can't find a solution, feel free to post a new question :)